# Adding spaces in front the string in a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

> Write the JavaScript to prompt the user to enter an odd number. First, check that the user has entered a valid odd number. Then you need to print to the console a cross made of the same number of * characters as the number the user entered.

So far I have my code as such

**I've edited my code to include the proper way**

```
let num = prompt("Enter an odd number");
let star = "*";
let vertical = "";
let horizontal = star.repeat(num);

while (num%2 == 0) {
    console.log("User did not enter an odd number");
    num = prompt("Enter an odd number");
}
console.log("User's number is " +num);
let pos = +(Math.ceil(num/2));
// I need to divide the input number by 2 and round up
for (var h = 0; h < pos; h++){
    vertical += (" ")

}

for (var v = 0; v < pos; v++){
    vertical += vertical + "\n *"
}
vertical += "*"
console.log (vertical)
```

I can get vertical to \n the proper amount of times but how would I go about making sure I don't over repeat the *?

Comment: Why not just say in the beginning `let vertical = ""` and then after the loop write `vertical += "*"`?

Comment: Yup, you are absolutely right. That was a very simple solution thank you for bringing it up.

Now any chance you would have an idea as to how I could repeat that vertically for num or pos amount of time? I tried using \n to repeat new line it but it doesn't quite work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. There are three steps that you need to do here. You need to create a cross like this (assuming number is 13):

```
   *
   *
   *
*******
   *
   *
   *
```

You need to create `Math.floor(13/4)` (comes out to 3) rows of a single star, with each star after `Math.floor(13/4)` spaces. Then you need a row of `Math.ceil(13/2)` stars starting at position 0. Lastly, you need the same number of stars as you did before that row, so you can just do the same thing again.

Using your code, I would do something like this:

```
let num = prompt("Enter an odd number");

while (num%2 == 0) {
    console.log("User did not enter an odd number");
    num = prompt("Enter an odd number");
}
console.log("User's number is " +num);

let star = " ";
let pos = Math.floor(num/4);
let vertical = star.repeat(pos) + "*";

for (var i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    console.log(vertical);
}

console.log("*".repeat(Math.ceil(num/2)));

for (var i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    console.log(vertical);
}
```

Comment: That's definitely closer to what I need. Although, I changed the math parts a little to be math.floor(num/2) and just .repeat(num) because I want the full amount the user input as * ;

is there a reason console isn't showing the complete new line with the *? it just shows the number (6) of how many times it repeats instead of showing all the *

Comment: That's just how certain consoles work. You might be able to change the settings on your browser. It does it to preserve space. Another possibility is to convert the entire cross into one large string that has multiple new line characters in it

Answer (score 1):

Initially you are assigning

```
let vertical = "*";
```

change it to

```
let vertical = "";
```

Try this

```js
let num = prompt("Enter an odd number");
let star = "*";
let vertical = "";
let horizontal = star.repeat(num)

while (num%2 == 0) {
console.log("User did not enter an odd number");
num = prompt("Enter an odd number");
}
console.log("User's number is " +num);
let pos = +(Math.ceil(num/2));
// I need to divide the input number by 2 and round up
for (var h = 0; h < pos; h++){
vertical += (" ")

}
console.log(vertical)
```